# show background-image based on screen resolution almost works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, haml

I'm trying to use 3 different size images for a full-screen background; one image for each of 3 different screen resolutions. It works except on initial load.

In the code below the background image displays, but it always shows the image for `screen.availWidth = 1360` on initial load. If you nav to another page it works fine.

Maybe some things don't get prepared in `$(document).ready`.

I'd sure appreciate any help with this.

Here's the code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #bkgrnddiv {
           min-width:100%;
           min-height:100%;
           margin:0;
           padding:0;
           background-position:center top;
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           overflow:hidden;
        }

        .bg1280_index{
           background-image:url('img1280/index.jpg');
        }

        .bg1360_index{
           background-image:url('img1360/index.jpg');
        }

        .bg1920_index{
           background-image:url('img1920/index.jpg');
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var url = window.location.pathname;   
          var pageName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);       
          pageName = pageName.substring(0, pageName.length - 4);

          if(screen.availWidth <= 1280) {
              $('#bkgrnddiv').removeClass("bg1360_" + pageName);   
              $('#bkgrnddiv').removeClass("bg1920_" + pageName);   
              $('#bkgrnddiv').addClass("bg1280_" + pageName);   
          } else {
              if(screen.availWidth <= 1366) {
                  $('#bkgrnddiv').removeClass("bg1280_" + pageName);   
                  $('#bkgrnddiv').removeClass("bg1920_" + pageName);   
                  $('#bkgrnddiv').addClass("bg1360_" + pageName);   
              } else {
                  $('#bkgrnddiv').removeClass("bg1280_" + pageName);   
                  $('#bkgrnddiv').removeClass("bg1360_" + pageName);   
                  $('#bkgrnddiv').addClass("bg1920_" + pageName);   
              }
          }
      });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="bkgrnddiv" class="bg1360">
       <!-- content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: where does `screen` come from?

Comment: `screen` is a built-in JS object. Not that it should make a difference, but have you tried using `window.screen` instead of `screen`?

Comment: I tried adding "window" to "screen", but no difference. I thought maybe the class was being reset in the div declaration for #bkgrnddiv after $(document).ready initialized it. Of course if I remove the class from the div declaration, then there is no background image onload.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using a CSS 3 Media Queries solution?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px)
{
   #bkgrnddiv {
       background-image: url('img1280/index.jpg');
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1360px)
{
   #bkgrnddiv {
       background-image: url('img1360/index.jpg');
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px)
{
   #bkgrnddiv {
       background-image: url('img1920/index.jpg');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to capture the page name from the initial load which only contains the IP. So now I test for page name == empty string. I also eliminated the additional background classes.

```
<head> 
    <style> 
        #bkgrnddiv { 
           min-width:100%; 
           min-height:100%; 
           margin:0; 
           padding:0; 
           background-position:center top; 
           background-repeat:no-repeat; 
           overflow:hidden; 
        } 
    </style> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var url = window.location.pathname;   
            var pName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            if(pName == ''){
                pName = 'index.php';
            }
            pName = pName.substring(0, pName.length - 4) + ".jpg";

            if(window.screen.availWidth <= 1280) {
                $('#bkgrnddiv').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images1280/' + pName + ')');   
            } else {
                if(window.screen.availWidth <= 1366) {
                    $('#bkgrnddiv').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images1360/' + pName + ')');   
                } else {
                    $('#bkgrnddiv').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images1920/' + pName + ')');   
                }
            }
        });
    </script> 

</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="bkgrnddiv"> 
       <!-- content --> 
    </div> 
</body>
```